# Vue.js - Helper function that accesses the app instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say I want to make a utility function that redirects users to a route if they aren't authenticated.

This function resides in a `utils.js` file; it isn't declared in any one component.

```
// utils.js
export function redirectIfNotAuthenticated (app, path) {
  if (!app.$store.state.isAuthenticated) {
    app.$router.push(path)
  }
}
```

this function is then `import`ed into single-file components and called like:
`redirectIfNotAuthenticated(this, '/login')`.

I think having an `app` parameter and having to explicitly pass `this` from the component is ugly. Is there a better way to have a stateless helper function access the scope of the calling component in vue? As in, is there a way to bind functions that don't live inside of a .vue file to the calling instance of the vue app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle redirection, instead of putting logic inside component, you can use vue-router's [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html) to handle on top level instead:

```
const router = new VueRouter({ ... })

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (!isAuthenticationRequired(to)) { // your logic to ignore authentication for custom routes, e.g. login 
    next();
  } else if (!isAuthenticated()) { // your logic which needs access to Vuex's store
    next('login');
  } else {
    next();
  }
})
```

Then, if you create a `store` object and add it to your Vue app instance, like in [the default example of Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store) , you can refer to the object directly without any need to access the Vue app, since same store object is used:

```
// utils.js
import store from '../your_path/your_file.js';

export function isAuthenticated() {
  return store.state.isAuthenticated;
}
```

Comment: +1. From a business logic, separation-of-concern standpoint, where would be the best place to define functions like `isAuthenticationRequired` in my project?

Comment: @SamueleB. Since the function take `to` as input, and likely nothing else from anything other parts (e.g. store, views, etc.), it can be a helper function for your router logic. Personally I would create a file named `utils/routingUtils.js` to put it inside, but it's more of personal taste.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in this situation is to use [router  navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) :

```
const router = new VueRouter({ ... })

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
   next(vm=>!vm.$store.state.isAuthenticated)
//vm refers to the vue instance
})
```